# Would you paraphrase this? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, inversion

> ... **.** Of importance is the fact that ... **.**

Does it have *Inversion*?

My guessed paraphrases would be: *"The fact is of importance that ... "* or *"The fact has importance that ... "* or *"The important fact is that ... "* which one is true?

Comment: Where did you see that, as a learner  I will choose the last one. I think you can also ask what is(are) the difference(s) among them.

Comment: @Cardinal you can see a lot of examples in link below: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Of+importance+is+the+fact+that%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More like:

> **What is** of importance is the fact that ...

The structure you quoted simply omits [What is].

An alternative way to say it is:

> What is important is the fact that ...